# Caps Lock in insert mode only

Tags: key-bindings, letter-case

Sometimes, such as when transcribing FORTRAN code, I find it useful to enter uppercase letters without holding down the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key.

However, enabling <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> is a problem in command mode. Here is my (admittedly inelegant) workaround:

```
function! AllCaps()
    inoremap a A
    inoremap b B
    inoremap c C
    inoremap d D
    inoremap e E
    inoremap f F
    inoremap g G
    inoremap h H
    inoremap i I
    inoremap j J
    inoremap k K
    inoremap l L
    inoremap m M
    inoremap n N
    inoremap o O
    inoremap p P
    inoremap q Q
    inoremap r R
    inoremap s S
    inoremap t T
    inoremap u U
    inoremap v V
    inoremap w W
    inoremap x X
    inoremap y Y
    inoremap z Z
endfunction

command! AllCaps call AllCaps()
```

I have an similar command called `NoAllCaps` that maps them back to normal. It does the job, but it's not pretty.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Have you looked at the Visual Foxpro syntax file, vfp.vim? There's a function or two in there that upper cases keywords. I don't understand them well enough to be able to modify them to work for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't as concise as my earlier solution (see below) or [statox's answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/13254/343), but it's much cleaner than the former and has the advantage over the latter in that it uppercases individual letters as you type:

```
function! AllCaps()
  augroup all_caps
    autocmd!
    autocmd InsertCharPre * call <sid>Capitalise()
  augroup END
endfunction

function! NoAllCaps()
  autocmd! all_caps
endfunction

function! s:Capitalise()
  let ascii_number = char2nr(v:char)
  if 97 <= ascii_number && ascii_number <= 122
    let v:char = nr2char(ascii_number - 32)
  endif
endfunction
```

The `AllCaps()` function sets up an autocommand to intercept keypresses during insert mode.

The `s:Capitalise()` function upper cases each individual keypress if it's a lower case letter.

The `NoAllCaps()` function simply removes the autocommand.

### Older Solution

This is a more concise version of your existing solution that creates the maps programmatically in a loop.

```
function! AllCaps()
  for letter in range(97,122)
    execute "inoremap " . nr2char(letter, 1) . " " . nr2char(letter - 32, 1)
  endfor
endfunction
```

### The capslock.vim Plugin

I have subsequently discovered Tim Pope's [capslock.vim plugin](https://github.com/tpope/vim-capslock/blob/master/plugin/capslock.vim), which uses both of the methods described above to implement this functionality.

### Alternative methods

You can also set up [language mappings](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#language-mapping) or a [keymap](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/mbyte.txt.html#mbyte-keymap) to translate lower to upper case and vice versa, [as described on the Vim Tips Wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Insert-mode_only_Caps_Lock).

Once set up, both of the above can be toggled by pressing <kbd>Ctrl+^</kbd>. (See [`:help i_CTRL-^`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/insert.txt.html#i_CTRL-%5E).) See the [linked page on the Wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Insert-mode_only_Caps_Lock) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the following lines to get an automated solution, I'm not sure if it is really prettier but it seems to be working and takes only 3 lines:

```
let g:capslockfortran = 1
nnoremap <F5> :let g:capslockfortran = !g:capslockfortran<CR>

autocmd InsertLeave * if g:capslockfortran | execute "normal! `[v`]U | `]" | endif
```

The first two lines create a variable `g:capslockfortran` initialized to `1` and a mapping (`<F5>`) which toggle the value of this variable between `1` and `0`

The third line creates an autocommand which is triggered each time you leave insert mode in fortran files *(I never wrote fortran before, it seems that the extension is `.f90` but you might want to change that if it is not the correct extension)*

The command executed tests the value of `g:capslockfortran` and if it is set to `1` it will select the last inserted text (`` `[,`] ``) and uppercase it with `U`.

**Edit** Thanks to @BLayer comments I also added `` `] `` so that the cursor doesn't change of position.

**Some notes:**

You could use `b:capslockfortran` instead of `g:capslockfortran` to be able to enable/disable the automatic uppercase on a buffer basis. That would probably require another autocommand which would initialize the variable for each buffer.

For more details you can have a look at the following help topics:

- [`:h autocmd-events`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#autocmd%2devents)
- [`:h InsertLeave`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#InsertLeave)
- [`:h '[`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#%27%5b)
- [`:h v_U`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#v_U)

Comment: @BLayer that's weird I just tried it again and it works for me... When do you get the error?

Comment: Sorry, that was user error. However, do you want to move the cursor back to the end of insertion? For me anyways, it remains at the beginning of insertion.

Comment: @BLayer no problem, the `execute` wasn't nessecary anyway (see my edit). About where the cursor ends up indeed there may be a problem. I guess one could try to add `\`]` at the end of the command to go back to the previous position, or use `getpos()` and `setpos()`

Comment: That seems reasonable. I just tried this and it seems to work okay (I'm leaving off the feature flag and `execute`) `au InsertLeave * normal! \`[v\`]U | \`]`.

Comment: @BLayer uh I edited with a call to `setpos()`, using the mark as you did is better I'll add it to the answer if you're okay. For the backtip in the comments I used `backtick-antislash-backtip-bracket-backtick` to escape the backtip to show in the text

Comment: Cool, sounds good. (And I just escaped backtick with backslash and that seemed to do the trick.)

Answer (score 0):

Are you okay converting the text after you enter it? If so, type in lowercase, select the text with Visual mode and type `U`.

Or avoid Visual mode with `gU{motion}`. (See `:help uppercase`)

Too easy? :)

Comment: That's what I've done previously, but it gets fiddly after a while.

Comment: @bariumbitmap Can you elaborate on 'fiddly'? What goes wrong?

Comment: Nothing goes wrong, but it's distracting to go back and re-select what I typed, and it makes it harder to catch typos while transcribing. Thanks for the tip, though; before I was using `~` instead of `U`.

Comment: Fair enough...'twas a low-tech suggestion to begin with.